# OAuth2 CORS call to Azure Web App protected with AAD using only Javascript

Tags: javascript, azure, oauth-2.0, cors, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to make CORS request to Azure Web Service that is AAD protected. App that is making call has no backend code - only html+js. 
I use adal.js, have everything setup (Azure Web App, adal.js config) and I'm able to use adal.js to receive token (I can check it's valid using Advanced REST client).

The problem is when I try to make call like below:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    // XHR for Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari.
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
} else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    // XDomainRequest for IE.
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
} else {
    // CORS not supported.
    xhr = null;
}
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.onload = function () { ... };
xhr.onerror = function (error) { ... };
xhr.send()
```

I receive

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load 
<myAppUrl>. Redirect 
from <myAppUrl> to 
'https://login.windows.net/<guid>/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code+id_token&redirect_uri=<myAppUrl>%2F.auth%2Flogin%2Faad%2Fcallback&client_id=<guid>&scope=openid+profile+email&response_mode=form_post&nonce=cdf7754a3d66498baad6809f3de0b0ae_20170910165538&state=redir%3D%252Fapi%252FValues' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is 
present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:59672' is 
therefore not allowed access.
```

I can only guess it's because Authorization header was not passed properly so target app wants to redirect me in order to login. And in fact no Authorization header is in the request...

If I'll try to add such header manually adding

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
```

I receive

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load 
<myAppUrl>. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)
```

I tried multiple tutorials (i.e. this [article](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/guidance/connect-to-api-secured-with-aad)) but there is always backend code that load some nuget packages - I have only html + js.

Dead end. Any ideas how to make it work? Is it even possible?

Comment: Where do you host app (JS+HTML)? If it is on Azure, try enabling CORS in Azure App settings.

Comment: In the first one you are receiving a redirect since the request is unauthenticated. Configuring your app to instead return a 401 status code might make more sense, since as you see, Azure AD does not allow cross-domain requests. Since your second one also does not work, maybe you have not configured authentication to use JWT bearer tokens? Could you add the authentication configuration here?

Comment: @PrzemekMarcinkiewicz: CORS is setup as it should be. If I open web service directly in the same session than the browser handles all the authentication and I can make CORS without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

@juunas: I had very same guess - it's somethink with authentication. Maybe adal.js does not handle that properly? Especially that as I wrote: no Authorization header is in any request...and AFAIK adal.js should handle all request and add such header (via http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/02/19/introducing-adal-js-v1/)
My config:

```
window.config = {
    instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
    tenant: '<myTenant>',
    clientId: '<myGuid>', //in old Azure Portal it calls: Client ID. In new Azure Portal it's Application ID'
    postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
    cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage', // Tried with localStorage as well
    endpoints: {
        // The domain of API (requsets are made TO)
        // And the same client id as above
        "<myAppUrl>": "<myGuid>"
    }
};
```